# oncomplete does not hide <p:dialog dynamic="true">

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I have a `<p:dialog dynamic="true">` which is shown on start of  `<p:commandButton>`.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton value="#{bundleComunes.guardar}" actionListener="#{saveBB.save}" onstart="PF('saveDialog').show()" update="@form" oncomplete="PF('saveDialog').hide()" />  
    <p:dialog dynamic="true" widgetVar="saveDialog">  
        Guardando<br></br> 
        <p:graphicImage value="/img/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

It shows dialog, but never hides on complete. But if I remove `dynamic="true"`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton ... update="@form" />
    <p:dialog dynamic="true">  
        ...
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

You're updating the form the dynamic dialog is sitting in, causing it to get corrupted because it's after the update not the same dialog anymore as when it was opened.

Change `update="@form"` to something more specific which does not cover the dialog, or, better yet, move the dialog outside the form, preferably to the very bottom of the body.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton ... update="@form" />
</h:form>
...
<p:dialog dynamic="true">  
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it on glassfish and it works fine.
I think you should have a look on `#{saveBB.save}` and check if it throws any exception.